# Android : Parse XML with Sax failed (goes to exception)

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, sax

I'm trying to parse an xml file with SAX.
I don't understand why it goes to exception. This code works in an other app I wrote a few weeks ago. 
This time I create an XML file :

### wifi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<main>

<wifi bssid="..." >

    <latitude>
        ...
    </latitude>

    <longitude>
        ...
    </longitude>

    <ssid>
        ...
    </ssid>
</wifi>

<wifi bssid="..." >

    <latitude>
        ...
    </latitude>

    <longitude>
        ...
    </longitude>

    <ssid>
        ...
    </ssid>
</wifi>

</main>
```

To parse this file, I use this code :

### WifiParser.java

```
    ...
    public static Vector<WifiDescription> parse(InputStream file) {
    Vector<WifiDescription> wifiDescription = new Vector<WifiDescription>();
    Log.d("XML", "test Parsage");
    try {
        // create a XMLReader from SAXParser
        XMLReader xmlReader = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
        Log.e("XML", "xmlReader");
        WifiHandler wifiHandler = new WifiHandler();
        Log.e("XML", "WifiHandler");
        xmlReader.setContentHandler(wifiHandler);
        Log.e("XML", "setContentHandler");
        xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(file));
        Log.e("XML", "parse");
        wifiDescription = wifiHandler.getWifiDescription();
        Log.e("XML", "wifi description");           
    } 

    catch(Exception ex) {
        Log.d("XML", "WifiParser: parse() failed");
    }

    return wifiDescription;
}
    ...
```

### WifiHandler .java

```
public class WifiHandler extends DefaultHandler {

public boolean isMain,isWifi,isLatitude,isLongitude,isSSID;

public int i;

public String tmpVal;

private Vector<WifiDescription> mWifiDescription;
private WifiDescription currentWifi;

/**
 * @return
 */
public Vector<WifiDescription> getWifiDescription() {
    Log.v("test parsage getWifiDescription","");
    return mWifiDescription;
}

@Override
public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
    // create new object
    i=0;
    Log.v("test parsage Start","");
    this.mWifiDescription = new Vector<WifiDescription>();
}


@Override
public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
    // nothing we need to do here
    Log.v("test parsage End","");
}

@Override
public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts)
        throws SAXException {
    Log.v("test parsage StartElement","");
    if(localName.equals("main")) {
        isMain=true;
        Log.v("test parsage main","");
    }

    if(localName.equals("wifi") && isMain ) {
        this.currentWifi = new WifiDescription();

        tmpVal = atts.getValue(WifiDescription.MSSID);
        this.currentWifi.mBSSID=tmpVal;
        isWifi=true;
    }

    else if(localName.equals("latitude") && isWifi ) {
        tmpVal = atts.getValue(WifiDescription.LATITUDE);
        this.currentWifi.mLatitude=Double.parseDouble(tmpVal);
    }
    else if(localName.equals("longitude") && isWifi ) {
        tmpVal = atts.getValue(WifiDescription.LONGITUDE);
        this.currentWifi.mLongitude=Double.parseDouble(tmpVal);
    }
    else if(localName.equals("ssid") && isWifi ) {
        tmpVal = atts.getValue(WifiDescription.SSID);
        this.currentWifi.mSSID=tmpVal;
    }
}

@Override
public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {

    Log.v("test parsage EndElement","");
    if(localName.equals("wifi")) {
        //System.out.println("passe dans End landmark");
        isWifi=false;
        i++;
        this.mWifiDescription.add(currentWifi);
    }
    Log.v("XML", "DONE \n");
}
```

}

And I call it in the mainActivity with :

### MainActivity.java

```
    ...
    public void returnTableParseXml(){
    try {
        wifis = WifiParser.parse(getAssets().open("wifi.xml"));
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        Log.d("XML Main","onCreate(): parse() failed");
        return;
    }
}
    ...
```

### logcat:

---

```
     07-10 11:00:07.460: E/XML(16482): xmlReader
     07-10 11:00:07.460: E/XML(16482): WifiHandler
     07-10 11:00:07.460: E/XML(16482): setContentHandler
     07-10 11:00:07.465: D/XML ex.getMessage(16482): null
     07-10 11:00:07.465: D/XML(16482): WifiParser: parse() failed
```

### ex.printStackTrace();

```
07-10 13:33:35.480: W/System.err(29590): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-10 13:33:35.480: W/System.err(29590):    at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:244)
07-10 13:33:35.480: W/System.err(29590):    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
07-10 13:33:35.480: W/System.err(29590):    at com.stage.ecolenavale.parser.WifiHandler.startElement(WifiHandler.java:66)
07-10 13:33:35.480: W/System.err(29590):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.startElement(ExpatParser.java:143)
07-10 13:33:35.480: W/System.err(29590):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.appendBytes(Native Method)
07-10 13:33:35.480: W/System.err(29590):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseFragment(ExpatParser.java:513)
07-10 13:33:35.480: W/System.err(29590):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:474)
07-10 13:33:35.480: W/System.err(29590):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:321)
07-10 13:33:35.480: W/System.err(29590):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:279)
07-10 13:33:35.480: W/System.err(29590):    at com.stage.ecolenavale.parser.WifiParser.parse(WifiParser.java:28)
07-10 13:33:35.480: W/System.err(29590):    at com.stage.ecolenavale.MainActivity.returnTableParseXml(MainActivity.java:420)
07-10 13:33:35.480: W/System.err(29590):    at com.stage.ecolenavale.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:161)
```

I don't understand why. Is it a probleme from my XML file ?

Comment: post the Handler and the logcat contest as well

Comment: Try to use `DefaultHandler` instead of `WifiHandler`

Comment: Can you please also add the message (and perhaps the stack trace) of the exception?

Comment: I have no messages from the exception. My app work but it doesn't parse the file. The only message i have from the exception is that the parse failed. I also add the handler.

Comment: Can you add this into your __catch__ clauses to see if that gives you more info?: __Log.d("XML", e.getMessage())__

Comment: when i add Log.d("XML", ex.getMessage()) the logcat shows "null"

Comment: you're getting a NullPointerException in your method __characters(char ch[], int start, int length)__ check if your instance variable __currentWifi__ is null (which I think is your problem)

Comment: oups. Yes I forget something : this.currentWifi=new WifiDescription(); But It still fail. I don't understand why my app fail when it enter in xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(file));

Comment: It seems I have a probleme with atts.getValue(WifiDescription. ..)

Comment: Thanks a lot Morgano. I didn't know the ex.printStackTrace(); command. It's really useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I used to parse a file with SAX:

### WifiHandler.java

---

public class WifiHandler extends DefaultHandler {

```
public boolean isMain;

public int i;

public String tmpVal;

private Vector<WifiDescription> mWifiDescription;
private WifiDescription currentWifi;

/**
 * @return
 */
public Vector<WifiDescription> getWifiDescription() {
    Log.v("test parsage getWifiDescription","");
    return mWifiDescription;
}

@Override
public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
    // create new object
    i=0;
    Log.v("test parsage Start","");
    this.mWifiDescription = new Vector<WifiDescription>();
}


@Override
public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
    // nothing we need to do here
    Log.v("test parsage End","");
}

@Override
public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts)
        throws SAXException {
    Log.v("test parsage StartElement","");
    if(localName.equals("main")) {
        isMain=true;
        Log.v("test parsage main","");
    }

    if(localName.equals("wifi") && isMain ) {
        this.currentWifi = new WifiDescription();

        tmpVal = atts.getValue(WifiDescription.MSSID);
        this.currentWifi.mBSSID=tmpVal;

        tmpVal = atts.getValue(WifiDescription.LATITUDE);
        this.currentWifi.mLatitude=tmpVal;

        tmpVal = atts.getValue(WifiDescription.LONGITUDE);
        this.currentWifi.mLongitude=tmpVal;

        tmpVal = atts.getValue(WifiDescription.SSID);
        this.currentWifi.mSSID=tmpVal;
        isWifi=true;
    }
}

@Override
public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {

    Log.v("test parsage EndElement","");
    if(localName.equals("wifi")) {
        //System.out.println("passe dans End landmark");
        isWifi=false;
        i++;
        this.mWifiDescription.add(currentWifi);
    }
    Log.v("XML", "DONE \n");
}
```

}

### WifiParser.java

---

```
public class WifiParser  {

public static Vector<WifiDescription> parse(InputStream file) {
    Vector<WifiDescription> wifiDescription = new Vector<WifiDescription>();
    Log.d("XML", "test Parsage");
    try {
        // create a XMLReader from SAXParser
        XMLReader xmlReader = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
        Log.e("XML", "xmlReader");
        WifiHandler wifiHandler = new WifiHandler();
        Log.e("XML", "WifiHandler");
        xmlReader.setContentHandler(wifiHandler);
        Log.e("XML", "setContentHandler");
        xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(file));
        Log.e("XML", "parse");
        wifiDescription = wifiHandler.getWifiDescription();
        Log.e("XML", "wifi description");           
    } 

    catch(Exception ex) {
        Log.d("XML ex.getMessage", "" + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();

        Log.d("XML", "WifiParser: parse() failed");
    }

    return wifiDescription;
}
```

}

### MainActivity.java

---

```
    public void returnTableParseXml(){
    try {
        wifis = WifiParser.parse(getAssets().open("wifi.xml"));
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        Log.d("XML Main","onCreate(): parse() failed");
        return;
    }
}
```

### WifiDescription.java

---

public class WifiDescription {

```
    // Description Wifi
    public String mLatitude;
    public String mLongitude;
    public String mBSSID;
    public String mSSID;
    public String mName;


    public static final String WIFI = "wifi";

    // vector usage
    public static final String LATITUDE = "latitude";
    public static final String LONGITUDE ="longitude";
    public static final String SSID = "ssid";
    public static final String MSSID ="bssid";
    public static final String NAME ="name";
```

}

### Wifi.xml

---

```
<main>
    <wifi
        bssid="..:..:..:..:..:.."
        latitude="..."
        longitude="..."
        ssid="..." >
    </wifi>
       ...
</main>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert attribute values that are not present in your XML file:

```
else if(localName.equals("latitude") && isWifi ) {
    tmpVal = atts.getValue(WifiDescription.LATITUDE);
    this.currentWifi.mLatitude=Double.parseDouble(tmpVal);
}
```

Here, `tmpVal` will be null, and hence the exception.

Before, you had

```
<wifi
    bssid="..:..:..:..:..:.."
    latitude="..."
    longitude="..."
    ssid="..." >
</wifi>
```

now, you have

```
<wifi bssid="..." >
   <latitude>
       ...
   </latitude>
</wifi>
```

so, the value you want is not an attribute, but the character content of the <lattitude> element. You must read that content using the `characters()`method. It will make the code more complicated, since you must collect the character content, and read it to the correct variable at `endElement`.

Comment: Yes. I change my code. I add it to the conversation. Thaks for your answer.